# servicio web HTTP 400: Bad Request

Tags: wcf

Tengo un web service WCF, el cual al ejecutarlo dentro de la solucion con VS2015 Pro, lo veo perfectamente (reitero, dentro de la misma solucion). mi problema, es que ahora estoy haciendo el deploy en el server (publish method: File System). y me aparece el siguiente error

```html
Error al descargar 'http://localhost:7000/AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.WS.Receta.Services/$metadata'.
Error de solicitud con el siguiente estado HTTP 400: Bad Request.
Los metadatos contienen una referencia que no se puede resolver: 'http://localhost:7000/AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.WS.Receta.Services'.
No había ningún extremo escuchando en http://localhost:7000/AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.WS.Receta.Services que pudiera aceptar el mensaje. La causa suele ser una dirección o una acción SOAP incorrecta. Consulte InnerException, si está presente, para obtener más información.
Error en el servidor remoto: (400) Solicitud incorrecta.
Si el servicio se define en la solución actual, intente compilar la solución y agregar de nuevo la referencia de servicio.
```

este error aparece al querer ejecutar desde otra solucion en VS2015 al querer agregarlo como referencia de servicio.

El web.config del servicio que estoy publicando (proceso desde VS) es el siguiente

```html
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.WS.Receta.Services" behaviorConfiguration="recetaBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.WS.Receta.IServices" behaviorConfiguration="" ></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="recetaBehavior">
          <!-- Para evitar revelar información de los metadatos, establezca los valores siguientes en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- Para recibir detalles de las excepciones en los fallos, con el fin de poder realizar la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true. Para no revelar información sobre las excepciones, establézcalo en false antes de la implementación -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

y la interface de mi servicio es:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.HL7;
namespace AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.WS.Receta
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServices
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "", Name ="RecibeReceta")]
        AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.HL7.ACKCONTENT GetRecetas_RDE_O11(AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.HL7.RDE_O11CONTENT Receta);


        [OperationContract(Action = "", Name = "RecibeProfesionales")]
        AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.HL7.ACKCONTENT GetProfesional_MFN_M02(AvisLatam.Certus.Accuro.HL7.MFN_M02CONTENT Profesionales);

    }
}
```

Los tipos de datos que devuelve el servicio, son tiipos complejos (por eso loo hice con WCF), y como decia anteriormente, desde la misma solucion en VS en otro proyecto, funcionan perfectamente.

Alguien me puede ayudar con este tema? 
Saludos Cordiales

Comment: ¿El error te aparece al intentar publicar el servicio o al intentar consumirlo?

Comment: Hola Gabriel, gracias por responder. El error me aparece al intentar consumirlo. en el momento de la publicacion, el VS lo hace correctamente, copia los archivos necesarios en la carpeta de destino sin problemas. pero al momento de agregar una referencia de servicio, aparece la ventana donde agrego el sevicio, escribo la direccion, y al presionar el boton IR, aparece el mensaje de error que indica que no encuentra nada.: 400 bad request

Comment: ¿El deploy lo haces en un servidor diferente? El error indica que el servicio se consulta en localhost. Verifica que tu endpoint sea el del server en el que se publica el servicio.

Comment: master, gracias por la ayuda, se trataba de un error en el server. el adm del servidor me indico que tenia algunos problemas con el IIS, y que al publicarlo generaba una caida. Graciaspor la ayuida de todas formas.